# For MVC5, can I have multiple display templates for same data type but have one be the default used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC5 I have multiple **'shared'** display templates for the same data type such as `DateTime`used with **multiple controllers** but I want one of the templates to be the one used unless I specifically state the template name.

Is there a way I can do the following:

1. Require that a display template only be used if it was specified using the 'UIHint' attribute or template name specified in `DisplayFor(x => x.Time, "templatename")`

OR

2. Indicate that a certain display template is used unless the template name is provided.

I am aware of placing the template in the controller's shared display template folder and the search order but I'm referring to multiple templates for the same data type being in the shared display template folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify a location (using `[UIHint]` of the 2nd parameter of `DisplayFor()`),templates are searched in the following order

```
/Views/YourControllerName/DisplayTemplates
```

if nothing is found, then

```
/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates
```

and if nothing is found, then the default (in-built) template for the property type is used.

Locate you `DateTime.cshtml` template in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` and it will be used unless you override it using `[UIHint]` or by specifying the location in `@Html.DisplayFor()`, or by including a specific template for the controller.

Comment: Thank you.  I am aware of this and use this for other examples **but** I want more than one 'shared' display template for the same data type.<br/>     
Therefore, placing in the controller's folder does not achieve what I am looking for.  However, using UIHint is something I do today but If I choose not to use UIHint or specify a display template for a data type and there are two templates in the 'shared' display template folder for the relative data type which one is used.

Comment: **LAST COMMENT TIMED OUT BEFORE COMPLETE** Thank you. Let me clarify my question further. I am aware of the "search order" and also of "UIHint attribute".  I left out that I want the templates for the same data type to be shared by multiple controllers.  Therefore, both would be placed in the 'shared' display template folder.  As a result, what template is used when I don't use UIHint or the template name? What would be the default template used and is there a way I can specify what that default template is - either by annotating it or by annotating that the others are **not** the default?

Comment: The file that has the same name as the data type is the default. You can only have one file named DateTime.cshtml so that will be the default. If you want to use an alternate template e.g. DateTimeAlt.cshtml you will have to explicitly specify it using UIHint or DisplayFor.

Comment: @Blake, As per the answer, if the file is named the same as type type (i.e. for `DateTime` - name the file `DateTime.cshtml`) and its located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder, then that template will be used as the default.